# Confused as to the right answer to this summation, am I wrong (most likely) or is the answer provided wrong?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

If you have $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty(4/5)^n$ and you are asked to represent it as a geometric series you would:

$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty(4/5)(4/5)^{n-1}$   //factor out your constant 
therefore $a = 4/5$, $r = 4/5$, $|r| < 1$ checks out. 
 
Using $a / (1 - r)$ you get $(4/5)/(1 - 4/5)$ 
$(4/5)/(1/5) = 4$. which confuses me because the solution said the answer was $5$?

Comment: Your sum is from $n=0$, so you should not factor out $a$....

Comment: "using $a/(1-r)$" only works for series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a r^n$, when $0<|r|<1$. The given series is already in this form (with $a=1$). It might be better to memorize the sum of a convergent geometric series via "the first term of the series divided by $1-r$".

Comment: Right right! How could I forget. Thank you for clearing that up. Post it as an answer if you'd like so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left(\frac45\right)^n$$

We use the fact that:

> $$\text{If}\;\;0 < r < 1,\,\text{ then}\;\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \dfrac{1}{1- r}\tag{*}$$

So we have $r = \dfrac{4}{5} < 1$.

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n = \frac{1}{1 - (4/5)} = 5.$$ 
Note: the "$1$" in the numerator of (*) can be thought of as the first term of the sum: $r^n$ at $n = 0 \implies r^0 = 1$.

Comment: One takes $0^0=1$ for the formula above.

Comment: Why do you think that? I can't see it...

Comment: @DonAntonio - are you asking me?

Comment: Sorry, I was asking @DavidMitra

Comment: @DonAntonio If the formula $(*)$ is to be true for $r=0$, then one has to take $0^0=1$ (just in interpreting this formula, of course).

Comment: I see, @DavidMitra. Thanks. Though it is common to disregard the case $\,r=0\,$ in geometric progressions (series), the formula (*) is true in fact for $\,|r|<1\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes. I made the comment (of course) because the $r=0$ case was not disregarded.

Comment: Then again, $0^0=1$ is simply true (cardinality of the set of functions from the empty set to itself). It's merely the problem that $x\to0$ and $y\to 0$ does not imply $x^y\to 1$.